# Bluetooth issue - iPhone 4S and iPhone5

Tags: ios, bluetooth

Two iPhones don't show each other when bluetooth is enabled. Any idea why that would be as both devices are in v4.0 with A2DP?

Thanks.

Comment: Bluetooth "classic" or Bluetooth Low Energy ?

Answer (score 0):

Find more information on `Core Bluetooth` [here](http://weblog.invasivecode.com/post/39707371281/core-bluetooth-for-ios-6-core-bluetooth-was) and [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/_index.html) to solve your issue and regarding information.